# Start reading data in query from end (of file)

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I would like to retrieve from a very large table the (`100`) most recent dates. This seems easy enough, however using something like this;

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM   [table] tbl
     WHERE  [some conditions]
     ORDER  BY tbl.date
     )
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
```

is extremely inefficient, since the entire table is read and ordered.

It is likely (but not guaranteed) that the most recent dates are at the end of the table. Now, for performance reasons I would like to take f.e. the last 1000 rows of the table that meet the set conditions and process those, without accessing the rest of the gigantic table.

I would like to know whether it is possible, through optimizer hints or otherwise, to make the SQL (or PL/SQL) code **start reading the table from the end of the file, and have it stop the query as soon as (f.e.) `1000` rows are selected?** (the same way the query stops when you add a `WHEN ROWNUM < 1000` to a simple select)

Comment: The whole table is not necessarily read; your conditions might be using indexes to reduce the amount of table data retrieved. But that's not really the point. 'From the end of the file' implies you think the data is stored sequentially somewhere. It isn't; it can be scattered pretty much randomly across the blocks that make up the tablespace. But the physical layout is abstracted away so you don't need to think about it, unless you have an IOT maybe. You have to find all the relevant rows and order them before you can apply your `rownum` filter, there isn't really any way around that.

Comment: *If* you have an index on the date field you *might* be able to order by that in an inner select, and then apply your conditions on the result of that, and then get the stopkey from the rownum. But depending on the data you could be increasing the amount of ordering, and not using indexes on other conditions properly, and you'd have to hint it, and it would be fragile at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an index on `tbl.date` and (this column is not nullable or you specify that you only want not null values in your WHERE clause) and the statistics are up-to-date, then the index should be used.

In most cases this kind of query would get a `INDEX FULL SCAN ASC/DESCENDING` access path like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TEST AS
  2  (SELECT SYSDATE + ROWNUM dt, RPAD('x', 100, 'x') DATA
  3    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1E5);

Table created

SQL> CREATE INDEX test_idx ON TEST(dt);

Index created

SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT *
  3    FROM (SELECT *
  4            FROM TEST
  5           WHERE dt IS NOT NULL
  6           ORDER BY dt DESC)
  7  WHERE ROWNUM <= 100;

Explained

SQL> SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3326882503
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |          |   100 |  6100 |     4   (0)|
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY                |          |       |       |            |
|   2 |   VIEW                        |          | 93692 |  5581K|     4   (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST     | 93692 |  5581K|     4   (0)|
|*  4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN DESCENDING| TEST_IDX |   100 |       |     2   (0)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This access path provides exactly the algorithm you're looking for: The index is read forward or backward until the required number of rows is returned.

If you're not getting this access path, it may be because you're searching for non-indexed values (NULLS) or there exists another access path that the optimize thinks is more efficient.